# Database structure and queries for a Twitter-like posts timeline

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql

I'm posting this question with a Django tag, because I'm working in this environment, but it's actually more or a generic question: I'd like to show something like my timeline on Twitter, i.e. a list of posts of all the people I am following ordered chronologically.

My typical database structure looks like this:

```
Table Name: Users
Columns:
    UserID PK
    EmailAddress
    Password

TableName: Friends
Columns:
    UserID PK FK
    FriendID PK FK

TableName: Posts
Columns:
    UserID PK FK
    Content
```

If I wanted to retrieve all posts of all the friends for a given user, it looks like this (this is not supposed to be valid SQL!):

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE UserID IN (LIST OF "Given user friends' IDs")
```

This works - no problem! However, this does **so not scale**! Let's assume we have a busy website and our given user has 2,000 friends and there are some ten million posts in the database. In such a scenario, the database query would be highly inefficient and slow.

Can this be solved with a relational database like PostgreSQL or MySQL? If not, how does e.g. Twitter do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A shorter version:

```
SELECT
    Posts.*
FROM
    Posts 
    JOIN Friends ON Friends.FriendID = Posts.UserID
WHERE
    Friends.UserID = 1 /* change as needed */ ;
```

You can check it with:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    UserID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    EmailAddress text,
    Password text
) ;

CREATE TABLE Friends
(
    UserID integer NOT NULL REFERENCES Users(UserID),
    FriendID integer NOT NULL REFERENCES Users(UserID),
    PRIMARY KEY (UserID, FriendID)
) ;

CREATE TABLE Posts
(
    PostID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    UserID integer NOT NULL REFERENCES Users(UserID),
    Content text
) ;

INSERT INTO Users 
VALUES 
  (1, 'a@b.com', 'pass1'),
  (2, 'b@b.com', 'pass2'),
  (3, 'c@b.com', 'pass3'),
  (4, 'd@b.com', 'pass4') ;

INSERT INTO Friends
VALUES 
   (1, 2),
   (1, 4) ;

INSERT INTO Posts
VALUES
    (1, 2, 'A post from User 2'),
    (2, 2, 'Another post from User 2'),
    (3, 3, 'A post from User 3'),
    (4, 4, 'A post from User 4') ;
```

and you should get:

```
+---+---+--------------------------+
| 1 | 2 | A post from User 2       |
| 2 | 2 | Another post from User 2 |
| 4 | 4 | A post from User 4       |
+---+---+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks joanolo! I've marked your answer as correct, because you've given a complete example. The other answers are equally correct. Yet, I was hoping for a more sophisticated solution along the lines of a NoSQL database, because the `JOIN` is still not efficient enough. I'm head developer at Pixabay.com - and our PostgreSQL database turns more and more into a reliable data storage, while all fast-to-read data is served by an Elastisearch server. It's working, but I was wondering if a NoSQL database is another way to go. How does Twitter or Facebook do it?

Comment: You need information from _two_ tables. You have to `join` them one way or another. Let the database decide which is the best way to do it. A NoSQL database is good to store whole documents (for instance: an article together with all the comments to it, that are always shown together). It is not normally good to perform a _join_ (which is what you want here). You may just need a _faster_ database (faster hardware, SSD disks, lots of memory so that most of your data fits into RAM, ...). And make sure you have all the proper indices. Could you send an execution plan?

Comment: WRT to what Twitter and Facebook do: I really don't know (and I don't think they will make this info public). But I think that they just use some technique that gives them an _approximate_ solution. BTW: Is a user with 2.000 friends realistic? If your problem is very much related to a _network_ of friends, you might want to take a look at *[graph databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database)* (such as [Neo4J](https://neo4j.com/)).

Comment: Oh, Graph database, never heard of that. Sounds like an interesting option for this use case. Thanks - also for the explanation about NoSQL!

Answer (score 2):

```
   SELECT p.*
     FROM Posts AS p
     JOIN (SELECT FriendID
             FROM Friends
            WHERE UserID = :given_user_id) AS f
       ON (p.UserID = f.FriendID)
```

scales much better. As you have marked your PK’s, you have all needed indexes in place already.

Answer (score 2):

You can also follow your own QUERY, it will work:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Posts
WHERE
    UserID in (SELECT FriendID 
                 FROM Friends 
                WHERE UserID = 1 /* whatever */ ) ;
```

This will scale (in latest versions of mySQL or PostgreSQL, it will produce the same execution plan as a JOIN).